# Concatenating and compiling uglified javascsript in closure compiler

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, google-closure-compiler

For some javascript packages I can only get the minified/uglified file. I need to combine them with my other javascript files and compile with google closure compiler.

My question is:

Is it preferable to pass the raw unminified javascript to closure compiler, instead of the uglified one? (in particular with the advanced optimization mode.)

Since many javascript library provide minified version itself(like jquery and angularjs), do I need to worry if I included those scripts in another minification task(uglify or closure compile). Or should I single them out and only concatenate them?

Comment: If a browser is able to understand a minified script, then a tool that claims to be a JS “compiler” should as well. Only problem that might arise is if the different minified scripts were to use identically named global variables … since minifying often contains renaming variables to “short” names like `a`, `b`, etc., that might happen. But good scripts would not use global variables anyway, right?

Answer (score 2):

If micro-optimisation is your thing, you might want to have a look at *several* minifiers to see which is the best fit for your codebase. The main ones are UglifyJS, Google Closure Compiler and ESMangle. There's a [nice comparison on the Uglify website](http://lisperator.net/blog/should-you-switch-to-uglifyjs2/). Running code through several minifiers may seem like overkill but if it yields better results then why not. :-)

Minifiers don't care if you pass in something thats already been minified; as an example I use the r.js optimiser in production, and that concatenates my unminified source code and minified jQuery and the like, then uglifies the whole lot.

You don't need to really worry about reminifying libraries, all it's going to do is add more time onto the build step, so if it's taking too long then you could split out the libraries from the minifier and simply concatenate them.

Comment: This really isn't true for Closure-compiler. The benefits of Closure-compiler (including type checking, static analysis and dead code elimination) are more than just minification. Runing already minified code through it isn't really what it was designed for, nor will you get great results.

Answer (score 1):

There are two paths depending on the library:

1. If the library provides the unminified source AND it is known to be compatible with `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` then the best option is to pass it in as a source file. This option reaps the benefit of dead code elimination on the library source as well as your source.
2. If the library only provides the minified source OR is known not to be compatible with `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`, then the best option would be to compile your code using externs for the library. For minimizing the number of requests, you should still concatenate the results together. While you could use the `WHITESPACE_ONLY` level of the compiler, it may not be the best tool for that.

Of course combining a library with your source will minimize requests, but will at the same time nullify any caching benefit from using a CDN for the library hosting.